# Cannot access one .txt file with two scripts

Tags: python, file, batch-file

Here is my problem :

I got a python program that writes into a file, and a batch one that reads the file then. So I got my python code (simplified) :

```py
import os
file = open("test.txt", "w")
file.write(Chooseentry.get()+"\n")
for i in hal:
    file.write(i+"\n")
file.close()
os.startfile (r"C:/Hack/Project/Read.bat")
```

So I start my batch after having closed the file. It is supposed not to be used anymore by python, right ?
But then my batch file that reads it tells me :

```
The system cannot find the file test.txt
The process cannot access to the file because this file is already used by another process
```

Soooo... How can I close properly my file in python so that I can use it with my batch then ?

Thanks by advance for any help ! ^^

Comment: Did you try to see which process is using the file?

Comment: Mmmh, no, I'm gonna check this, thanks !